# Copying detail from one side of an object to another?

Tags: edit-mode

If I had a cube like object with 6 main faces:

[image: cube]

and I added some detail to one side:

[image: detailed cube]

How can I copy what's on that one face to the 5 other faces? I know I can mirror to have a copy on the opposite side, but what about the other 4 faces?

While taking screenshots for the question, I managed to figure out how to make it work for uniform/regular shapes. I'm still interested anyone who has an answer for how to do this when the faces are not in regular locations.

Comment: Please see also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34818/how-do-i-copy-one-side-of-a-box-and-paste-it-on-the-rest-of-the-sides

Answer (score 2):

This method only works for objects derived from uniform/regular shapes:

First select all vertices you want copied:

[image: Selected]

Then `Shift+D` to duplicate, `P -> Separate by selection` to separate new that part.

Go back into object mode, select the new part and rotate 90 degrees (if its a cube) to the face you want it on.

[image]

Duplicate rotate the new object to other positions you want it on.

[image]

Select the original object, go into edit mode and delete the faces that are now occupied by the new objects

[image]

Back in object mode, select everything and press `Ctrl+J` to join them back into one object.

Now press `A` to select all, `W -> Remove Doubles` to remove the duplicated vertices and join new faces back together with the original object

[image]

And you are done!